# Extract first block of consecutively matching lines from a file?

Tags: text-processing

So I have a file like this:

```bsh
echo 'this line is added for demo purpose'
echo 'do not extract this line and the line above'

#!/usr/bin/env bash
# header: add, replace, and delete header lines.
# 
# Example usage:
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'values'
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'VALUES' | header -e 'tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"'
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'values' | header -d
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'multi\nline' | header -n 2 -e "paste -sd_"
#
# See also: body
#

# Author: http://jeroenjanssens.com

usage () {
cat << EOF
header: add, replace, and delete header lines.

usage: header OPTIONS

OPTIONS:
...
}

# i don't want
# these comments

# even if 
# these lines match
```

And I want to extract all the lines matching regex `^(#.*)|(\s*)$`,
from the first line in the file that matches, *consecutively* to the last line that matches.

The desired result of extraction should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# header: add, replace, and delete header lines.
# 
# Example usage:
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'values'
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'VALUES' | header -e 'tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"'
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'values' | header -d
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'multi\nline' | header -n 2 -e "paste -sd_"
#
# see also: body
#
# Author: http://jeroenjanssens.com
```

How do I do this?

I think I can extract all consecutively matching lines with regex in multiline mode, but I only want the first part of the match.

Update:

I want regex `^(#.*)|(\s*)$` to match

- comments with a `#` at the beginning of the lines
- empty lines (like the one after `# Author`)
- lines only contain empty spaces

Comment: what happened to the empty line before `# Author...` line? and also rest of the line `# See also: body....`, and how `See` changed to `see` there?

Comment: @αғsнιη Thanks for the comment. I want the empty line after `# Author` to be matched by regex `^(#.*)|(\s*)$` and be extracted. The see also part was an editing mistake and it's now fixed. :)

Comment: your edit still didn't address what I pointed. also better explain what is your goal instead of saying you want to match `^(#.*)|(\s*)$`.

Comment: @αғsнιη My goal is to extract the usage info at the beginning of the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk '/^#/{f=1} f && !/^#|^[[:space:]]*$/{exit} f' ip.txt
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# header: add, replace, and delete header lines.
# 
# Example usage:
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'values'
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'VALUES' | header -e 'tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"'
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'values' | header -d
# $ seq 10 | header -a 'multi\nline' | header -n 2 -e "paste -sd_"
#
# See also: body
#

# Author: http://jeroenjanssens.com
```

This will start extracting lines when the first comment is found and continue to print as long as a line is a comment or a line with zero or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed. Without trailing spaces:

```
sed '/^#/,$!d;:1;/^\s*$/N;/\S/!b1;/^#/M!Q' file
```

`/^#/,$!d` - Cut off lines before the start of comments.
`:1;/^\s*$/N;/\S/!b1` - If there are empty lines or only spaces, add to the buffer(pattern space).
`/^#/M!Q'` - if a line is encountered that does not start with a comment mark, exit the script (`M` - Anchors will be valid in a multiline buffer).

With trailing spaces:

```
sed '/^#/,$!d;/^#\|^\s*$/!Q' file
```